# Checking if element exists in unorderd_set before inserting it

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I would like to ask if there is any point of checking if element exists in `unorderd_set` before inserting it? According to [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/insert/):

> Each element is inserted only if it is not equivalent to any other element already in the container (elements in an unordered_set have unique values).

So if I'm getting it correctly in my case:

```
Element *element = new Element;
//...
if ( my_set.find (element) == my_set.end() )
    my_set.insert(element);
```

It is not required - correct? What actually happens if I try to insert element that is already in the set. Does it do exactly the same check that I am doing?

Comment: Read the docs, Luke: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and don't traffick in Raw Pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to insert a value that is already present, the set will remain unchanged. The call will return a pair containing an iterator and Boolean. The Boolean will be false if the item was already present.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert

Note that in your case where the set contains pointers it will only prevent you from having duplicate pointers, not duplicate contents. For example,

if your `Element` object represented an element, like Oxygen, it might contain a value for the atomic number and a string for the name. If you only want oxygen to appear once, a set of pointers will not automatically do this.

Comment: I don't get what you want to say with your last sentence... If you have to equal pointers (same address) of the same type: what content is/can be duplicate in in your opninion?

Comment: @SimonKraemer If there is some aspect of the Element objects that he is trying to keep unique, using a set of pointers will not do that.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I appreciate the question.

Answer (score 2):

An `insert()` on `unorderd_set` does a `find()` to see if the object exists and then inserts the object.

So in your code they are two `find()`, one explicit, and other inside the `insert()`